# How to have URL suggestions right inside the Firefox address bar (rather than in a list below it)?

Tags: firefox

Before reinstalling Windows on my machine, when typing "am" in Firefox address bar I immediately got "amazon.co.uk" and just had to hit enter. Now I first need to go down the suggestion list below and then select "amazon.co.uk".

How to get the same state as I had before?

Comment: Maybe clearing history cache can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to get the same state as I had before?

> When typing "am" in Firefox address bar I immediately got "amazon.co.uk" and just had to hit enter.
>
> Now I first need to go down the suggestion list below and then select "amazon.co.uk".

1. Navigate to `about:config`
2. Set `browser.urlbar.autoFill` to `true`:

   [image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [Changing autocomplete behavior - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Disabling_autocomplete_%28Firefox%29)
- [Awesome Bar - Search your Firefox bookmarks, history and tabs from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Location%20bar%20autocomplete)

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm curious though how did you find this info?

Comment: @drake035 Hehe. I have high google-fu ;) "firefox url autocomplete" first and second results. Then I tested with my firefox.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! Firefox keeps having updates that change how the address bar works for me, and one a month or two ago changed mine to only suggest from the Bookmarks, not from the History, which was driving me nuts. The first further link section "Changing Location Bar autocomplete behavior" showed me how to fix this. Yay!

Comment: @Dronz You're very welcome! :)